# SQL sp_executesql makes strange complaints

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Why do this code give this error message?

```
exec sp_executesql N'AddCallExe',N'@stepResultId int,@exitCode int',@stepResultId=46469,@exitCode=-1073741510
go
```

Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure AddCallExe, Line 0
Procedure or function 'AddCallExe' expects parameter '@stepResultId', which was not supplied.

EDIT:
Thank you for the help it helped me spot the real underlying problem stated below.

The solution and real problem was an underlying C# line was missing:

```
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

and cmd is defined as:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the parameters from the statement itself, so this will work:

```
exec sp_executesql 
    N'AddCallExe @stepResultId,@exitCode',
    N'@stepResultId int,@exitCode int',
    @stepResultId=46469,
    @exitCode=-1073741510
```

Just wondering why would you even call a procedure with sp_executesql...